# AttributeError: 'DiscordClient' object has no attribute 'edit_role'

Tags: python, discord.py

I try to change role color on a Discord server using [discord.py](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).
But after running it I got the error:
`AttributeError: 'DiscordClient' object has no attribute 'edit_role'`

Code:

```
import discord
import os
import asyncio
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv
load_dotenv()

discord_token = os.environ['your_discord_bot_token']

class DiscordClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("Login as")
        print(self.user)
        print("-------")
        server = discord.utils.get(self.guilds)
        print(server)
        role = discord.utils.get(server.roles)
        print(role)
        await self.edit_role(server=server, role=role, 
                             hoist=True, colour=discord.Colour(0xe91e63))

client = DiscordClient()
client.run(discord_token)
```

Bot successfully login, print `server` and `role` as expected. After googling and looked into documentation can't found the answer. I have all the permissions to edit roles (I'm tested bot on my own server). This `edit_role` is not deprecated, on closed issues from [github](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aclosed) I also can't find anything helpful

Comment: does your bot have the needed admin privileges / role to be allowed to take that action?

Comment: @Pizzalord, I checked this - my bot have admin privileges and can operate on roles

Comment: where are you settings who's role to edit, or are you trying to edit the bots role?

Comment: @Pizzalord, I tried to edit role at a server. As Patrick answered, discord.py have a migration guide, where many methods from current docs are outdated. So my fault here is used methods from old docs, which currently unsupported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Client.edit_role` has been removed and replaced with [`Role.edit`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Role.edit) as of the 1.0 version (you can check your version with `print(discord.__version__)`).

Whatever resource you're working off of is outdated.  You should read the [migration guide](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html) to get an idea of the changes that have been made, and search the documentation if you suspect a method or coroutine has been moved.

```
class DiscordClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("Login as")
        print(self.user)
        print("-------")
        server = discord.utils.get(self.guilds)
        print(server)
        role = discord.utils.get(server.roles)
        print(role)
        await role.edit(hoist=True, colour=discord.Colour(0xe91e63))
```